# Run RFTagger in Python

Tags: python, command-line, nlp

I want to use RFTagger (http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/RFTagger/) in my Pyhton code. The only way that I got it to work is like this:

```
file = open("RFTagger/temp.txt", "w")
file.write(text)
file.close()
test_tagged = check_output(["cmd/rftagger-german", "temp.txt"], cwd="RFTagger").decode("utf-8")
```

Is there an easier / faster way? Or is there a similar library that can give the same output? I especially need it for German.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lot faster if you run it like this:

```
from subprocess import check_output, run
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

#run this once
run(["make"], cwd="RFTagger/src")

#run this for every text (text is a string)
file = open("RFTagger/temp.txt", "w")
file.write("\n\n".join("\n".join(word_tokenize(sentence, language='german')) for sentence in sent_tokenize(text, language='german')))
file.close()
test_tagged = check_output(["src/rft-annotate", "lib/german.par", "temp.txt"], cwd="RFTagger").decode("utf-8").split("\n")
```

I could reduce runtime from around 40 seconds per text to 1.5 seconds.